# How do I change my user icon on here to my normal avatar I use everywhere?

Tags: support, user-profile

That green star next to my name is annoying, yet I haven't seen a link where I can upload my own avatar.  I see other people with custom images, and I am hoping some-one can give me step-by-step instructions how to put mine up.

Comment: See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/41278/157803)

Comment: @Wipqozn @Nick-t -- I actually found the link to `Change Picture`.  The reason I was not finding it was because I was looking for an edit here on _meta_, and the only link to edit my profile is in _main_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adapted from ["How do I change my profile picture, or avatar?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-do-i-change-my-profile-picture-or-avatar)

> Your picture/avatar is tied to the **Gravatar** — for "globally recognized avatar" — linked to your e-mail address.
>
> #### How do I change my profile picture, or avatar?
>
> 1. Go to [Gravatar.com](http://en.gravatar.com/)
> 2. Create a profile and upload a picture.
> 3. Add that e-mail address to your Stack Exchange profile.
> 4. Wait a few hours for it to propagate.
> 5. You might need to clear your cache to have the new image requested.
>
> #### How can I use different avatars on different SE sites?
>
> 1. [Associate your Stack Exchange profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-stack-overflow-accounts-users-anon).
> 2. Change your e-mail address on the sites for which you want a different avatar.
> 3. Follow the steps in **How do I change my profile picture, or avatar?** (above) for the new address.
>
> #### How do the SE sites know when I changed my Gravatar?
>
> The SE sites directly link to these Gravatar images from gravatar.com, so that when it is updated on Gravatar, it will be updated immediately on the SE sites as well. You may need to clear your cache to see the changes, though.
>
> [According to Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/url), your email address is hashed and used in your avatar's URL. For example, in the URL `http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6b40908a8b13c9c7eecfcb95960cc0f6?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG`, the portion `6b40908a8b13c9c7eecfcb95960cc0f6` is your email's md5 hash, provided you have an email address associated with your account.